# String to Date type casting issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, casting, string-conversion

I am trying to typecast the string data to date but it works with some date but not for others. I am using the `convert()` function

**Example**

When I give this value to the `string` parameter it works fine

```
select  Convert(DATE, '01/05/2017', 101)
```

[image]

but trying the same code with a different but correct date doesn't work and gives the below-shown error

```
select  Convert(DATE, '13/06/2013', 101)
```

[image]

I am getting the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 Conversion failed when converting
> date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Please refer to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) `Style 101` is `mm/dd/yyyy`. You should be using `style 103` `dd/mm/yyyy`

Comment: it depends of your database language, i think in your case, SQL Server is considering 13 in your second exemple as a month.

Comment: Considering you're using literals, why not use a completely unambiguous format, such as `yyyyMMdd`? Then you don't need the style code.

Comment: More the point: the first example is also being parsed wrong, it thinks it's 5th Jan not 1st May.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Squirrel mentioned in the comments the right style is `103` , from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

[image]

```
select  Convert(DATE, '01/05/2017', 103) as my_date;
my_date
2017-05-01

select  Convert(DATE, '13/06/2013', 103) as my_date2;

my_date2
2013-06-13
```

I will suggest never store dates as text, you can create another column with datetime (even though this is out of the question scope) and update the column like the example below:

```
create table test (
wrong_date_format varchar(25)
);

insert into test values 
('01/05/2017'),
('13/06/2013');

ALTER TABLE test ADD wright_date_format date;

update test set wright_date_format = Convert(DATE, wrong_date_format, 103);
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7632e9cc1b0fb321777be5c55c50a6cf)

Comment: this is right answer

Answer (score -2):

@Muhammad Waheed Please check this might be helpful to u..

```
select  Convert(DATE, Cast('13-Jun-2013' as date), 101)
```

because  SQL Server is considering 13 in your second exemple as a month. that's why causing error.

Comment: If you're going to suggest the OP use a different format string literal, why chose one that is also language bound?